# some data are not inserted in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

here i have the php code for connection and insertion of data to the database.
tfs.php :-

```
  <?php
     require "init.php";
$fsname = $_POST['fsname'];
$lsname =$_POST['lsname'];
$contact =$_POST['contact'];
$password =$_POST['password'];
$rent_on =$_POST['rent_on'];
$room_status =$_POST['room_status'];
$room_for =$_POST['room_for'];
$quantity =$_POST['quantity'];
$beds_status =$_POST['beds_status'];
$study_table =$_POST['study_table'];
$wifi =$_POST['wifi'];
$gizer =$_POST['gizer']; 
$city =$_POST['city'];
$area =$_POST['area'];
$college =$_POST['college'];
$mail_id =$_POST['mail_id'];
$address =$_POST['address'];
$pcode =$_POST['pcode'];
$geo =$_POST['geo'];

   $sql = "INSERT INTO `user_record`(`fsname`,`lsname` , `rent_on`,`room_status`,`city`,`area`,`college`,`room_for`,`quantity`,`beds_status`,`study_table`,`wifi`,`gizer`,`contact`,`password`,`mail_id`,`address`) VALUES ('$fsname','$lsname','$rent_on','$room_status','$city','$area','$college','$room_for','$quantity','$beds_status','$study_table','$wifi','$gizer','$contact','$password','$mail_id','$address')";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo "<br><h3> Data submitted....</h3>";
}
else
{
    echo "Error in insertation..." . mysqli_error($con);
}
 ?>
```

and here is the html code :-

```
           <html>

           <head><title>Add info...</title></head>

           <body>

           <form action="tfs.php" method="post">
           <table>
           <tr>
            <td>First Name :</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="fsname" /></td>
          </tr>
          <td>Last Name :</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="lsname" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <tr>
          <td>rent on :</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="rent_on" /></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>room status :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="status" /></td>
       </tr>
       <td>city :</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="city" /></td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>area :</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="area" /></td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>college :</td>
       <td><input type="text" name="college" /></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
       <td>room for :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rent_for" /></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>quantity :</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="quantity" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>bed status :</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="bed" /></td>
           </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>study table :</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="s_table" /></td>
           </tr>
         <tr>
       <td>wifi :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="wifi" /></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
       <td>gizer :</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="gizer" /></td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
       <td>Contact :</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="contact" /></td>
       </tr>
            <tr>
          <td>password :</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="password" /></td>
           </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>mail id :</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="mail_id" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>Address :</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
         </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>postal code :</td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="pcode" /></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
             </table> 
             <input type="submit" value="Submit Info" />
                </form>
           </body>

           </html>


the connection between database is successful but some values like pcode, geo, rent shows doesn't have default values. The error is as shown in image.
```

[the status of connection is successful but showing the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHwin.png)

here is the structure of database:- 
      [the database contain 11 fields,when i will change the default values of pcode, geo, rent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THL5O.png)
 then [data inserted but some field shows empty and some are NULL.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhaKl.png)

so i don't know what to do now.Give the solution of that problem.

Comment: HI. Please read about SO stack snippets & also [mcve]s. Also please [use text, not links/images, for text, including tables & DDL](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3404097).

Answer (score 0):

Check your Name assigned in the HTML page relevent to $_POST in PHP.

For Example:

```
$room_status =$_POST['room_status'];
```

There are no fields in HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the some fields in your insert query  sno,pcode,geo & rent ,your post should be:

```
$room_status =$_POST['status'];
$room_for =$_POST['rent_for'];
$beds_status =$_POST['bed'];
$study_table =$_POST['s_table'];
```

query:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `user_record`(`sno`,`fsname`,`lsname` , `rent_on`,`room_status`,`city`,`area`,`college`,`room_for`,`quantity`,`beds_status`,`study_table`,`wifi`,`gizer`,`contact`,`password`,`mail_id`,`address`,`pcode`,`geo`,`rent`) VALUES (NULL,'$fsname','$lsname','$rent_on','$room_status','$city','$area','$college','$room_for','$quantity','$beds_status','$study_table','$wifi','$gizer','$contact','$password','$mail_id','$address','$pcode','$geo','rent')";
```

You code is open to sql injection ,use prepared statements, sanitize your variables,don't forget to secure your password

Comment: And you also forgot to add them columns in your solution.. add pcode and geo after `mail_id`,`address`

Comment: @giollianosulit what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your sql is vulnerable; please convert your queries to prepared and include security measures.
2. you're missing the pcode column in your query. When you don't include a column i.e. ( `INSERT INTO tbl (col1,col2) VALUES ('col1','col2');` ) But, your table has a col3 and the table is set up as `create table tbl (col1 id not null auto_increment, col2 varchar(5), col3 boolean)`. When you insert in your current query, the SQL is left assuming that you have a default value in pcode(col3) because you declined to supply it in the column declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try insert statement like and check values against each variable easily

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `user_record` SET 
        `fsname` = '".$fsname."',
        `lsname` = '".$lsname."',
        `rent_on` = '".$rent_on."'........
```